# how do i change this code so that it instead writes to a string?

Tags: c#, string, memory, shared, var

hello i have this part of my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Memory mapped file reader started");

    using (var file = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("sensor"))
    {
        using (var reader = file.CreateViewAccessor(0, 3800))
        {
            var bytes = new byte[4051];

            Console.WriteLine("Reading bytes");
            for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                Console.Write((char)bytes[i] + "");

            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit ...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

which opens the shared memory and then writes it to var bytes and displays it. how would i instead write it to a string? i know it has something to do with "var bytes = new byte[4051];" but i cant write "byte" to a new string obviously.

PS the output of the code now(with the array) is simple text: ABCDEFG... etc

thanks

Comment: Your code never reads from the file. You're just going to write each character successively to the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's textual information you're trying to write, just pick encoding, and use `GetString` on the data.

```
 var encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
 Console.WriteLine(encoding.GetString(bytes));
```

If it's binary data you want to display textually (as in hex), then you'll need an extension method or otherwise to convert it.

```
static string ToHex(this byte[] data) {
    var builder = new StringBuilder(data.Length * 3);
    foreach (var b in data)
        buidler.Append(b.ToString("X2") + " ");
    return builder.ToString();
}

....

Console.WriteLine(bytes.ToHex());
```